# How to test InAppPurchase Subscription renewal in sandbox mode

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, auto-renewing

I am using InAppPurchase to sell subscription to users with one month plan.
Setup is done and i can test Purchase flow, but renewal is not working in sand-box mode.

I am using billing library version 4

```
  implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0'
```

[image]

After successfull purchase while validating receipt on server side getting autoRenew param in json with value blank. After 5 min plan is expired as describe in [doc](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test), but as per doc auto renew will expires after 6 times. In my case after first purchase auto renew not happening.

Can any one help me in this where i am wrong in this.
I already spent 4 days in searching for this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot I'm deducing you are in India.

A few months ago, Google has announced that it would pause new signups of auto-renewing subscriptions for users in India:

> Subscriptions will continue to be available as single access passes that provide users a single billing period of access (eg. 1-month access). At the end of the billing duration, Google says users will need to sign up again in order to continue their subscription.

source: https://www.xda-developers.com/google-play-suspend-free-trials-auto-renewing-subscriptions/

Maybe you should try to test on another market.